# How to Schedule YouTube Upload with Simple API wrapper?

Tags: video, youtube, upload, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

https://pypi.org/project/simple-youtube-api/

So I'm using this API wrapper to upload videos to YouTube. I've managead to do that.

I want to know if there's a way to schedule videos rather than just private/public?

I know that the actual YouTube API has a publish_at option. Maybe I can incorporate that into this if that's possible? Or if I can do it directly from this wrapper?

I'm a bit stuck so any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

video.set_publish_at()  # YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sZ